# Flowpaper Zine, How to show pdf in single-page mode instead of two-page mode, by default?

Tags: flexpaper

When I open a document in Zine PHP server side, it opens in two-page mode. 
I have to click on menu bar in order to switch to single-page mode.
Is there anyway to open the PDF document in single-page mode by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the following parameter to force single page mode:

InitViewMode : 'Portrait',